# CasperJS `assertField` fails with undefined value after `fill`

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs, functional-testing, casperjs

I can't seem to get this assertion to pass. I've added other asserts for verifying the existence of the fields and some other things to try to get this to work, but no luck. I feel like I might be overlooking something obvious.

**test_file.js**

```
var dropdownBtn     = '.btn.dropdown-toggle';
var signinForm      = '#signin-form';
var signinDropdown  = '.dropdown-menu';

casper.start(host + '/');

casper.then(function () {
    this.test.assertUrlMatch(host, 'Guest should not be redirected');
    this.test.assertExist(signinForm, 'Signin form exists');
    this.test.assertExist(dropdownBtn, 'Signin button exists');
    this.test.assertExist('[name="nickname"]', 'Nickname field exists');
    this.test.assertExist('[name="password"]', 'Password field exists');
});

casper.thenClick(dropdownBtn, function () {
    this.test.assertVisible(signinDropdown);

    this.fill(signinForm, {
        'nickname':    'bleep',
        'password':    'bloop'
    }, false);

    this.test.assertField('nickname', 'bleep'); // undefined
    this.test.assertField('password', 'bloop'); // undefined
});

casper.run(function () {
    this.test.renderResults(true);
});
```

**login.html**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu allow-click">
    <form method="post" action="#" id="signin-form">
        <div class="controls nickname">
            <label for="field-signin-nickname">Nickname</label>
            <input type="text" name="nickname" id="field-signin-nickname">
            <img class="maker-image">
        </div>
        <div class="controls password">
            <label for="field-signin-password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="field-signin-password">
        </div>
        <div class="controls pull-right">
            <input id="signin-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit" value="Go!">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**output**

```
Test file: test/functional/test_file.js
PASS Guest should not be redirected
PASS Signin form exists
PASS Signin button exists
PASS Nickname field exists
PASS Password field exists
PASS Selector is visible

FAIL "nickname" input field has the value "bleep"
#    type: assertField
#    subject: false
#    inputName: "nickname"
#    actual: null
#    expected: "bleep"
FAIL "password" input field has the value "bloop"
#    type: assertField
#    subject: false
#    inputName: "password"
#    actual: null
#    expected: "bloop"
FAIL 8 tests executed in 10.252s, 6 passed, 2 failed.

Details for the 2 failed tests:

In test/functional/session_signin.js:0
   assertField: "nickname" input field has the value "bleep"
In test/functional/session_signin.js:0
   assertField: "password" input field has the value "bloop"
```